# Translate Woocommerce tab

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, plugin-wpml, tabs

I have added a new tab in Woocommerce but I can not find how to add translation to it (I am using WPML plugin)
do anyone has an idea how to deal with that?
I need translation of the content of title
This is my code snippet :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
// Adds the new tab
    $tabs['desc_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'TEXTTTT', 'woocommerce' ),
        'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
    );
    return $tabs;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you shouldn't reuse the `woocommerce` textdomain as it means forking woocommerces translations which will be difficult and cause problems on update. it's significantly easier to add your own translations with your own textdomain instead, then you could follow generic advice and ignore WooCommerce. For WPML advice you should ask in a WPML community though, user dev support questions for 3rd party plugins/themes/products such as WPML/WooCommerce are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope